# Why does Invoke-Sqlcmd -OutputAs DataTables return different types for one vs many records

Tags: sql-server, powershell, datatable

PowerShell 5.1

```
$tblOutput = Invoke-Sqlcmd ... -OutputAs DataTables
```

Why does `Invoke-Sqlcmd` return a `DataRow` type when 1 record is return from database vs `DataTable` when greater than 1?

I would have expected that it returns `DataTable` regardless.

```
$successResults = $tblOutput.where({ $_.Flags -eq 36 -And $_.Result -eq 1 })
```

Preceding gets an error saying `where` is not defined on `DataRow`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like an <strike>unfortunate bug</strike> which can be reproduced with the following example:

```bash
$result = & {
    $dtt = [System.Data.DataTable]::new()
    $dtt.Columns.AddRange(@('Name', 'Value'))
    $row = $dtt.NewRow()
    $row.Name  = "Hello"
    $row.Value = "World"
    $dtt.Rows.Add($row)
    $dtt.GetType() | Out-Host # => DataTable
    $dtt
}

$result.GetType() # => DataRow
```

However as a workaround, you can add this [`DataRow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow?view=net-6.0) to a new [`DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-6.0):

```bash
$dtt = [System.Data.DataTable]::new()
$dtt.Columns.AddRange(@($result.Table.Columns.ColumnName))
$dtt.Rows.Add($result.ItemArray)
$dtt.where{ $_.Name -eq 'Hello' }
```

---

Not a bug! Just PowerShell trying to enumerate the output from the script block. Since there is only one element in the `DataTable`, the return type is `DataRow`.

Another way to reproduce it:

```bash
$dtt = [System.Data.DataTable]::new()
$dtt.Columns.AddRange(@('Name', 'Value'))
$row = $dtt.NewRow()
$row.Name  = "Hello"
$row.Value = "World"
$dtt.Rows.Add($row)
$dtt.GetType() # => DataTable
$(foreach($i in $dtt) { $i }).GetType() # => DataRow
```

Or even shorter, as [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) points out in his helpful comment, since [`$( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--) already enumerates, the `foreach` loop is not needed:

```bash
$($dtt).GetType() # => DataRow
```

Comment: Other (easier) workarounds: use the [Comma operator `,`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#comma-operator-) for the function output: `,$dtt` or the [`Write-Output -NoEnumerate $dtt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output#parameters) parameter whch than always returns a `datatable`.

Comment: Good point @iRon, do you think a proxy command is feasible using one of these in the wrapper?

Comment: Not sure, as I do not quiet understand where it goes wrong for the questioner (@Rod) also taking his [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72581009/1701026) in account where he apparently gets different results.

Comment: @iRon I think you can answer [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72585395/15339544) see the comment section. `$PSCmdlet.WriteOutput($dtt, $false)` would be another option if the function was advanced

Comment: *meant `$PSCmdlet.WriteObject($dtt, $false)` typo