# PowerShell 5.1 Why same query on different 2016 sp1/sp3 databases return different types

Tags: sql-server, powershell

PowerShell 5.1
SQL Server 2016 SP1 and SP3

If I run an identical `select top 1` query between 2 SQL Server 2016 databases (one is on sp3, other is sp1) they return different types, why?

```
$res = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select top 1 * from customer" -ServerInstance "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" -Database "Database1" -OutputAs DataTables
$res.GetType()
$res
```

One database returns a `DataTable` and other returns `DataRow`

[image]

Comment: Tbh, if it really returns 2 different types in 2 different versions of the module it might be an actual bug. However since this is proprietary code from MS it's hard to tell you if this was intended or not.

Comment: It might be worth adding the Module versions on sp1 and sp3 and clarifying on which version the return type is the expected one.

Comment: If you copy/paste the commands via e.g. email, watch out for [em dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67175721/1701026)

Comment: What you show is the expected (`datatable`) results, can add/show the unexpected (`datarow`) results?

Comment: Does this happen on different computers? Or maybe different Windows accounts on the same computer? What's the output of `Get-Command -Name Invoke-Sqlcmd` in both places?