# PowerShell 5.1 Why are these 2 functions returning different types

Tags: powershell

```
function Main {
    $result1 = DoWork1
    $result1.GetType()

    $result2 = DoWork2
    $result2.GetType()
}

function DoWork1 {
    $result1 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select top 1 * from customer" -ServerInstance "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" -Database "Database1" -OutputAs DataTables
    #assign to variable then return
    return $result1
}

function DoWork2 {
    #return results without assigning to variable
    return Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select top 1 * from customer" -ServerInstance "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" -Database "Database1" -OutputAs DataTables
}

Main
```

Here is the unexpected output:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                    
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                    
True     False    DataRow                                  System.Object                                                                               
True     True     DataTable                                System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent
```

Comment: Could it be simply because there is no default order in the db when select is used without order by ?

Comment: What happens if you change `return $result1` for `return , $result1`?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon ok that worked, but why? put an answer with some insight and I'll mark it, thanks.

Comment: Waiting for [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72580495/why-does-invoke-sqlcmd-outputas-datatables-return-different-types-for-one-vs-ma/72580732#comment128216084_72580732) to see if he wants to answer this one as he came up with this. Basically, the comma operator makes so the DT is wrapped in an array which then when being outputted is unwrapped from that array and because of this, the DT instance is untouched

Comment: @santiagosquarzon - The same happens if the expression is simply, e.g. ```$result1 = new-object system.collections.arraylist``` instead of ```Invoke-SqlCmd …```. It looks like returning a variable triggers unrolling, but returning the same expression directly doesn’t unroll. Using the comma operator to create a “sacrificial array” is a good workaround, but I’d be interested in knowing *why* returning a variable is different to returning the same expression directly. Maybe that’s “just what it does”? :-)

Comment: @mclayton it is confusing I agree but what I think it happen is, `Invoke-Sqlcmd` outputs `DataTable` _as expected_ and assigned to `$result1`, then `DoWork1` unrolls the `DataTable` into a `DataRow`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - sure. It’s just an interesting observation that in *most* languages you’d expect that assigning the result of an expression to a variable and returning the variable would be semantically identical to returning the result of the expression directly, but then again, PowerShell isn’t *most* languages :-).

Comment: @mclayton, as for the design rationale behind enumerating the value of _expressions_ in the pipeline: It is in line with the fundamental nature of PowerShell pipelines as streams of individual objects of indeterminate length. By contrast, `Invoke-SqlCmd ...` is a _command_ and as such its output isn't subject to enumeration (commands are expected to do their own streaming).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a similar example from the previous Q&A, to reproduce the same behavior:

```bash
function Invoke-SqlExample {
    $dtt = [System.Data.DataTable]::new()
    [void] $dtt.Columns.Add('Name')
    $row = $dtt.NewRow()
    $row.Name  = "Hello"
    $dtt.Rows.Add($row)
    , $dtt
}

function Main {
    $result1 = DoWork1
    $result1.GetType()

    $result2 = DoWork2
    $result2.GetType()
}

function DoWork1 {
    $result1 = Invoke-SqlExample
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Function = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
        Type     = $result1.GetType().Name
    } | Out-Host
    return $result1

    # Immediate fixes:
    #     return , $result1
    #     Write-Output $result1 -NoEnumerate
    #     $PSCmdlet.WriteObject($result1, $false) !! Only if Advanced Function
}

function DoWork2 {
     return Invoke-SqlExample
}

Main
```

The output you would get from this is:

```bash
Function Type
-------- ----
DoWork1  DataTable


IsPublic IsSerial Name            BaseType
-------- -------- ----            --------
True     False    DataRow         System.Object
True     True     DataTable       System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent
```

We can see that the unrolling of the `DataTable` is only done when previously assigned to a variable, even though the variable (`$result1` in `DoWork1` is still of the type `DataTable`).

This could be explained as, `DoWork2` happens in a single pipeline as opposed to `DoWork1` which happens in two pipelines, first the output from `Invoke-SqlExample` is collected in a variable, and then emitted as output (*this is where the unrolling is triggered*). This is based on assumptions, and may not be entirely correct.

As [iRon suggested in his helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72580495/why-does-invoke-sqlcmd-outputas-datatables-return-different-types-for-one-vs-ma#comment128216084_72580732) from the prior answer, an immediate fix to have `DoWork1` return the `DataTable` instance untouched (*unrolled*), we can use the [comma operator `,`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#comma-operator-) which will wrap the `DataTable` instance in an array which is then lost during enumeration (output from the function) since it is an array of one element. The other alternative would be using [`Write-Output -NeEnumerate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-7.2#parameters). As last alternative we can also use [`$PSCmdlet.WriteObject(..., $false)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.writeobject?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#system-management-automation-cmdlet-writeobject(system-object-system-boolean)) **only if the function is an advanced one**.

---

Adding a similar example that demonstrates the same behavior, this one was provided by [mclayton in his helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72585395/powershell-5-1-why-are-these-2-functions-returning-different-types#comment128219848_72585395):

```bash
function test {
    , [Collections.Generic.List[string]]@(
        'hello'
        'world'
    )
}

(& { test }).GetType()          # => List`1
(& { $a = test; $a }).GetType() # => Object[]
```

Comment: FWIW, I think the ```return``` statement is behaving differently for the variable vs the direct expression - if you try this ```(get-command DoWork1).ScriptBlock.Ast.Body.EndBlock.Statements[1].Pipeline.PipelineElements[0].GetType()``` you'll see that ```$result1``` in ```return $result1``` is a ```CommandExpressionAst```, but ```(get-command DoWork2).ScriptBlock.Ast.Body.EndBlock.Statements[0].Pipeline.PipelineElements[0].GetType()``` gives a ```CommandAst``` for ```Invoke-SqlCmd ...``` in ```return Invoke-SqlCmd ...```. I suspect that a ```CommandExpressionAst``` gets unrolled...

Comment: ... but a ```CommandAst``` does *not* get unrolled. I can't find any smoking gun in the PowerShell Core source though, so that might all be a red herring :-)

Comment: @mclayton `DoWork2` happens on a single pipe as opposed to `DoWork1` where first output from `Invoke-SqlExample` has to be collected first in the variable (1 pipe) and then emitted as output of the function (2nd pipe). I don't think `return` has any relation with this (the `Generic.List` example demonstrates `return` is not needed to reproduce)

Comment: @mclayton reg my previous comment, it's what I think / assume could be happening that can explain this, tho I may be incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72586305/45375) and [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton)'s helpful comments:

Note:

- The use of [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Return) is *incidental* to the behavior, given that `return ...` is merely *syntactic sugar* for `...; return`, i.e. outputting `...`, followed by exiting the scope; at the *end* of a script or function, `return` is never *required*, as the function / script is exited anyway. *Any* statement in a script or function can produce output, due to PowerShell's *implicit* output behavior - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792182/45375).

The **behavioral difference** comes down this:

- **`Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query ...` is a *command***, so whatever it outputs is output *as-is* to the  success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) of the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines) in which the enclosing function runs.

  - A command in PowerShell is a unit of functionality you invoke *by name*, which comprises cmdlets, scripts, functions, external programs, and [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks).
  - Commands *invariably* involve a pipeline whose success output stream they directly write to - whether or not *multiple* commands are connected with `|`.
- By contrast, **`$result1` is an *expression***, and if an expression evaluates to a value of a .NET type that PowerShell considers an enumerable,<sup>[1]</sup> it is ***enumerated* when it is sent to the success output stream (of a pipeline)**, which in the case of a a collection means sending its elements *one by one*; note that the original collection type is therefore *lost* in the process.

  - As for the *rationale* for performing such enumeration: It is in line with the fundamental nature of PowerShell pipelines as *streams of individual objects of indeterminate length* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020105/45375).
  - An expression in PowerShell is a construct that involves any combination of variable references, literals, most [operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators), and .NET method calls. ***In an of itself*, an expression does *not* involve a pipeline**, and collections and enumerables are treated *as themselves*. (An expression may have *nested* pipelines, however, if *commands* participate in it.)
  - **A pipeline - and therefore enumeration - *does* get involved** when an expression is used in the **following contexts**:

    - When you enclose the expression in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) or `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--); e.g. `$(1+2)` or `@(1+2)`

      - Note: `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) does *not* do that when applied to an *expression*: in the context of a larger expression, it merely clarifies precedence. However, when applied to a *command* instead (only *one* supported, e.g., `(Get-ChildItem).Count`), it runs the command to completion in a *nested* pipeline, collects its output object(s) and either returns them as-is, if there's only *one*, otherwise as an `[object[]]` array.
    - When you *pipe* the expression to a command, using `|`, the [pipeline operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#pipeline-operator-); e.g. 
      `1..3 | ForEach-Object { 1 + $_ }`. Note that expressions are only allowed as the *first* segment of pipeline.
    - When you *output* the expression - whether implicitly or explicitly (with the rarely necessary [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output)), whether in combination with `return` or not - *from inside a command*, such as in the case of outputting `$result1` from your `DoWork1` function.

The **upshot**:

- **If you store a *command*'s output in a variable** (`$result1 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query ...`), and **later output that variable's value to the success output stream** (`return $result1` or just `$result1` or `Write-Output $result1`), you potentially introduce an ***additional layer of enumeration***.

  - To *prevent* enumeration, you can use the techniques mentioned in Santiago's answer (transitory single-element array wrapper trick constructed with unary `,` - `, $return1` - or `Write-Output`'s `-NoEnumerate` switch - `Write-Output -NoEnumerate $return1`)
- However, this **only matters for commands that output collections *as a whole, as a single object***, instead of *streaming* collections, i.e *enumerating* them and outputting their *elements*, *one by one*, which is the *typical* case.

  - **Commands that output collections as single objects are *rare***, not least because the **general expectation of PowerShell commands is that they indeed *stream* their output**.
  - `Invoke-SqlCmd -OutputAs DataTables` *is* such a command, only because PowerShell - perhaps surprisingly - considers [`System.Data.DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Data.DataTable) instances *enumerable* - it conceives of it as a *collection of rows*, which it enumerates in the pipeline by default.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530467/45375) for an overview of what types PowerShell considers enumerable. In short: PowerShell has several exceptions where it considers types that declare themselves to be enumerable *not* enumerable, and one opposite exception: [`System.Data.DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Data.DataTable) does *not* declare itself enumerable, yet PowerShell enumerates it, namely as the collection of its *rows* stored in the `.Rows` property; Santiago provided the relevant [source-code link](https://ps.abco.live/#System.Management.Automation/engine/runtime/Binding/Binders.cs,612).</sup>

Comment: I always enjoy reading your answers - by about the second or third level of bullets it’s normally pretty easy to guess who wrote them :-). The key take-home for me was ```Invoke-SqlCmd …``` is a *command* not an *expression*, and they’re treated differently.